# laravel query model with condtion and related model with another condition in same query

Tags: laravel, model, eloquent

Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
$results = Community::with('floorplan')
                    ->where('communities.city', '=', 'Miami')
                    ->where('floorplans.number_of_bedrooms', '=', $bedrooms)
                    ->get();
```

I have two models, Community and Floorplan.  The relationship is Community has many Floorplans.  The relationship is set up properly.

How do I get all communities from Miami that have the same number of bedrooms? City is on communities table.  Number of bedrooms is on the floorplans table.  Do I need a raw query and a join?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```php
$query = Community::with('floorplan')->where('city', 'Miami');

$query->whereHas('floorplan', function($query) use ($bedrooms)
{
    $query->where('number_of_bedrooms', $bedrooms);
});

$results = $query->get();
```

You can of course chain it all if you want. Just separated it here for clarity.

Comment: Fantastic.  It seems so much easier/simpler using mysql, however.